# Kombu for RabbitMQ dosen't call callbacks method on consume after cancel_by_queue

Tags: python, rabbitmq, kombu

I wrote a simple queue consumer from RabbitMQ (using kombu):

```
import socket
from kombu import Connection, Exchange, Queue

def handle_message(payload, message):
   payload = int(message.payload)
   index = payload % 1000
   print('queue%s: ' %(index+1) + message.payload)
   message.ack()

while True:
    try:
        # connections
        with Connection('amqp://1000:1000@localhost:5672//1000') as conn:

            while True:
                chan = conn.channel()
                chan.basic_qos(prefetch_size=0, prefetch_count=10, a_global=False)

                with conn.Consumer(channel=chan,  callbacks=[handle_message]) as consumer:
                    queue = Queue('queue1', routing_key='queue1', exchange=Exchange())
                    consumer.add_queue(queue)
                    consumer.consume()

                    try:
                        print('before drain_events')
                        conn.drain_events(timeout=5)
                        print('after drain_events')

                        consumer.cancel_by_queue('queue1')
                        if not consumer.consuming_from('queue1'):
                            consumer.recover(requeue=True)
                    except socket.timeout as e:
                        print('timeout')

    except Exception as e:
        print("An exception was caught %s", e.message);
```

In this code I add a queue ("queue1") to the consumer and start consuming from it, and after each drain_event remove the queue using cancel_by_queue.

The result that I'm getting is that in the first round of drain_event the callback "handle_message" is being called but not in the next iterations. 
Am I using it wrong??

output:

```
before drain_events
queue1: 6221
after drain_events
before drain_events
after drain_events
before drain_events
after drain_events
before drain_events
after drain_events
before drain_events
.
.
.
```

If I put

```
with Connection('amqp://1000:1000@localhost:5672//1000') as conn:
```

inside the inner loop it works - but I don't want to create a new connection every time I remove a queue and start consuming from it again.

Thanks

Yaniv